# confused about Android's 'preferExternal' manifest filter

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-sdcard

The Android docs say:

> The .apk file is saved to the external
>   storage, but any application data
>   (such as databases) is still saved on
>   the internal device memory.

So what I'm supposing is that anything in your /raw or other resource goes with the the apk onto external storage, eh?

Also, does the download from the Market go straight to external storage, or do you have to have room for the app on internal storage so that it can download it and them move it when the download is complete?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best option is to use "auto". 
Sometimes, using preferExternal causes problem during installation. 
The system crashed trying to install the application on external memory (eg when the sd card isn't plugged in).

So the best choice is "auto", at least in my opinion.

Hope it helps,
Bye